# getcontext and savecontext behave differently under optimizations

Tags: c

I tried to implement fibonacci with getcontext and setcontext. The thing worked fine when compiling without optimizations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
static int result = 0;
static ucontext_t ctx; 


// fibonacci through get and set context 
int fib(int k, int l, int m ) {
    static int time = 0;
    getcontext(&ctx);

    time++;
    printf("In fib, time: %d\n", time); 
    int p = k; 
    k = l;
    l = p + l;
    printf("(k,l): (%d, %d) > %d\n", k, l, m);

    if(k > m){
            printf("k > m: %d > %d\n", k, m);
            return result;
    } 

    setcontext((const ucontext_t *)&ctx);


    return 0; // will never happen


 }

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int f = fib(1,1,100);
    printf("fib(1,1,100): %d\n", f);


}
```

However, when doing this with optimizations (tested on gcc and clang), it started looping forever.

Output before:

```
 
In fib, time: 1
(k,l): (1, 2) > 100
In fib, time: 2
(k,l): (2, 3) > 100
In fib, time: 3
(k,l): (3, 5) > 100
In fib, time: 4
(k,l): (5, 8) > 100
In fib, time: 5
(k,l): (8, 13) > 100
In fib, time: 6
(k,l): (13, 21) > 100
In fib, time: 7
(k,l): (21, 34) > 100
In fib, time: 8
(k,l): (34, 55) > 100
In fib, time: 9
(k,l): (55, 89) > 100
In fib, time: 10
(k,l): (89, 144) > 100
In fib, time: 11
(k,l): (144, 233) > 100
k > m: 144 > 100
fib(1,1,100): 0
```

Output after optimizations:

```
In fib, time: 1
(k,l): (1, 2) > 100
In fib, time: 2
(k,l): (1, 2) > 100
In fib, time: 3
(k,l): (1, 2) > 100
In fib, time: 4
(k,l): (1, 2) > 100
In fib, time: 5
(k,l): (1, 2) > 100
```

It seems that under optimizations, k and l are kept constant, while time is updated. I know I shouldn't use these functions, because they are deprecated and I won't. I was just toying around.

I tried to understand the behaviour from the manual, but somehow I can't explain the behaviour. I think there is a clear reason, because clang and gcc give the same output.

So, my question is, why does this little program behave so different under optimizations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In effect, your program exhibits undefined behaviour, and that is what you are seeing.

The context functions are not part of the standard C library and they are no longer part of the Posix standard, but that is not why your program has undefined behaviour. The problem is that `getcontext` and `setcontext` must be used with the same restrictions as `setjmp` and `longjmp` (which are still part of standard C). These restrictions are described in the C standard (and should be described in manpages). In particular, read [§7.13.2.1 paragraph 3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.13.2.1p3). After a `longjmp` (as with `setcontext`):

> … the values of objects of automatic storage duration that are local to the function containing the invocation of the corresponding setjmp macro that do not have volatile-qualified type and have been changed between the setjmp invocation and longjmp call are indeterminate.

In particular, the parameters `k` and `l` fall into this category (objects of automatic storage duration / local to the function calling `getcontext` / have been changed). So their values are indeterminate, and optimizations are not required to preserve them. And they don't.

**Note:** Since the context functions​ no longer appear in Posix, it is difficult to substantiate the above. Older Posix versions don't appear to mention the need to declare local variables as `volatile` if they might change, although there is an off-hand comment in the Gnu libc manual. Perhaps it is just part of programming folklore. But it is nonetheless true: the optimizer is not aware of context functions, and is not required to be aware of `setjmp` either, so it does not know that the code following `getcontext()` may be executed more than once. Therefore it has no reason to ensure that local variables are really modified unless they are `volatile` in which case it has no choice in the matter.

Comment: Indeed if I declare k and l as volatile, both behave the same. And when I looked at the assembly output I also saw it was ordered in such a way, that l and k couldn't change anymore, that is explained by that the optimizer is not aware of the context functions. Thanks!